# Meta Navigation: Exclude deleted/unpublished pages programmatically

Tags: 2013, csom, navigation, term-store, managed-navigation

I am accessing the managed metadata navigation term set via CSOM in a Web Service.

This term set includes many navigation terms that are configured to use friendly URL term driven pages, which are deployed as Publishing Pages in the Pages library.

The problem hereby is that I still access and deliver navigation terms where the original target page is not published or existing anymore.

Is it possible to query the navigation term set programmatically in a way where the "invalid" navigation terms are already pre-filtered, like in the standard SharePoint behavior when using Managed Metadata Navigation?